# Column value not updating properly in firebase database

Tags: java, android

I have an android studio project based around training games. At the end of a game, the user's score is calculated and displayed in a toast message, then saved to the firebase realtime database.

However, when the user completes a game, instead of adding to the existing score in the database, it is being overwritten.

Is there any way that I can get the score to update with the number of points gained in each game, rather than overwritten each time?

Below is the code for a quiz game, after hitting submit the score is saved in the database. If the user logs out and plays again and scores 3, I would like the current score in the database to increase by 3, rather than overwrite and become 3

```js
package com.example.securityapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class phishing_questions extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox financial, kindness, humour, postal, virtual, electronic, grammar, urgency, accuracy, highLevel, lowLevel, all, email, text, coldcall;
    Button score, finished;
    ProgressBar questionProgress;
    DatabaseReference databaseUsers;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    int grade = 0;
    int progress = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phishing_questions);

        questionProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        questionProgress.setMax(5);
        questionProgress.setProgress(0);

        final Context currentContext = this;
        finished = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);
        score = (Button) findViewById(R.id.final_score);
        databaseUsers = database.getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


        score.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (financial.isChecked()) grade++;

                if (electronic.isChecked()) grade++;

                if (urgency.isChecked()) grade++;

                if (highLevel.isChecked()) grade++;

                if (text.isChecked()) grade++;


                Users.currentUser.setScore(grade);
                databaseUsers.child(Users.currentUserId).setValue(Users.currentUser);

                Toast.makeText(currentContext, "You scored " + grade + " points!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                grade = 0;

            }
        });


        financial = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.financial_gain_checkbox);
        kindness = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.kindness_checkbox);
        humour = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.humour_checkbox);
        postal = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.postal_checkbox);
        virtual = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.virtual_checkbox);
        electronic = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electronic_checkbox);
        grammar = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.good_grammar_checkbox);
        urgency = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.urgency_checkbox);
        accuracy = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.accuracy_checkbox);
        highLevel = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.high_level_checkbox);
        lowLevel = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.low_level_checkbox);
        all = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.all_employees_checkbox);
        email = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.via_email_checkbox);
        text = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.via_text_checkbox);
        coldcall = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.via_coldcalls_checkbox);
    }

    public void questionOneProgress() {
        if (financial.isChecked()) questionProgress.setProgress(progress++);
        else if (kindness.isChecked()) questionProgress.setProgress(progress++);
        else if (humour.isChecked()) questionProgress.setProgress(progress++);
    }




    public void FinishedOnClick (View view)
    {
        finished.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent_finished = new Intent(phishing_questions.this, rating.class);
                startActivity(intent_finished);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }





}
```

Comment: Im not sure your title makes much sense based on the content of the post

Comment: Ah yes sorry about that, was mixing up two different issues I’m having! Thanks :)